# Removing top/bottom padding from UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, kingfisher

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that has a `UIImageView`.  I pull images from the internet to populate the image view in the cells so the aspect ratio can be different for each image.  I would like to avoid top/bottom padding in the `UIImageView` when the images width is greater than its height.

IE:
[image]

I also want to keep the aspect ratio the same.  I have the custom table view cell laid out in a `storyboard` with constraints pinning the side to each margin, and the top and bottom.  I also have a constraint for the UIImageView's height.  I then try and change that height constraint based on the aspect ratio of the original image.

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher
import AVFoundation

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func populateCell(url: URL?) {

    if let imageUrl = url {
        if let url = URL(string: imageUrl) {
            image.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: UIImage(named: "placeholder"), options: [], progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { (theImage, error, cacheType, url) in
                if let theImage = theImage {
                    let rect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: theImage.size, insideRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.image.frame.width, height: 250))
                    self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = floor(rect.height)
                }

            })
        }
    }
}  
}
```

This works great the first time.  I get the original image, figure out its aspect ratio based on the UIImageViews width/height.  However if I scroll down and back up to my first image things get wonky.  Originally the UIImageViews frame is **size : (343.0, 250.0)**, however on the second time the UIImageViews frame is 1000/1000.

Couple things:

1. I am not sure why the UIImageViews width/height is 1000/1000, seems very strange.  Either a cell recycling thing, or setting the height constraint messed up the size later.
2. Is what I am attempting ok, meaning is it valid solution?  If not is there a good way to resize the `UIImageView` height based upon the aspect ratio of the image, considering I am using a `UITableView` with auto layout and auto height.

Comment: Found any solutions?

Comment: d= (-_- ) Same here, don't give up!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, we was using something like `Height >= 123` constraint,
and changing it to equal (instead of greater-than) removed unexpected padding.